# GAE channels with java modules

Tags: java, google-app-engine, module, channel, gae-module

Got an java app consisting of two modules "default" and "abc". "default" contains my web interface which served over https and "abc" is some back end logic which is served over http only. Now, my goal here is to have a web client ("default") opening a channel and listen for messages sent from my module "abc".

So, I have followed the documentation and I got it to work locally on the devserver, but when deployed in production the web client doesn't receives any messages.

Basically it's very simple, web client creates a channel and receives a token from "https://my-app.appspot.com", then my other module ("http://abc.my-app.appspot.com") starts to post messages on the very same channel, but as I mentioned it only works locally and not in production.

Do I need to create the channel and post messages to the channel from the same subdomain using the same protocol schema? To me it seems odd since really the both modules belonging to the same app.

There are no errors or messages in the logs and I'm using latest (1.9.8) gae sdk.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Channels API only works on default module: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10293

Comment: Thank's, for what it's worth for anyone else having the same issue I ended up using a TaskQueue forwarding any messages from "abc" module to "default" module. This however wasn't trivial either (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10457). It's working now, however the solution is not perfect since using TaskQueue also means additional quota costs, but I guess this is Google's business model.